# How to put docker registry read only (in order to safely garbage collect)?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

https://docs.docker.com/registry/garbage-collection/ indicates

"Note: You should ensure that the registry is in read-only mode or not running at all. If you were to upload an image while garbage collection is running, there is the risk that the image’s layers are mistakenly deleted leading to a corrupted image."

But if I stop the registry container, then I cannot execute the garbage collection. I do not see how I can switch to read only mode.

Here is how I start the garbage collection:

```
docker exec registry bin/registry garbage-collect --delete-untagged /etc/docker/registry/config.yml
```

And how the registry is started:

```
docker run -d --restart=always --name registry \
        -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:5000 \
        -e "ENABLE_CORS=true" \
        -e REGISTRY_HTTP_HEADERS_Access-Control-Allow-Origin='["*"]' \
        -p 5000:5000 \
        -v /registry-storage:/var/lib/registry registry:2
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't have enough rep to comment.

To add to excellent [BMitch's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596285/bmitch) answer I'd like to note that I had to use

`-e REGISTRY_STORAGE_MAINTENANCE_READONLY="{\"enabled\":true}"` as suggested [here](https://github.com/distribution/distribution/issues/2974) to enable read-only mode.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [readonly configuration option](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#readonly), so you could restart the registry with:

```
docker run -d --restart=always --name registry \
        -e "REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:5000" \
        -e "REGISTRY_STORAGE_MAINTENANCE_READONLY={\"enabled\":true}" \
        -e "ENABLE_CORS=true" \
        -e REGISTRY_HTTP_HEADERS_Access-Control-Allow-Origin='["*"]' \
        -p 5000:5000 \
        -v /registry-storage:/var/lib/registry registry:2
```

Or you could just mount the volume as read-only:

```
docker run -d --restart=always --name registry \
        -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:5000 \
        -e "ENABLE_CORS=true" \
        -e REGISTRY_HTTP_HEADERS_Access-Control-Allow-Origin='["*"]' \
        -p 5000:5000 \
        -v /registry-storage:/var/lib/registry:ro registry:2
```

If you go with the latter option, or just decide to shutdown the registry, GC can be run in a separate container, it's not required to use an `exec`:

```
docker run --rm \
    -v /registry-storage:/var/lib/registry \
    --entrypoint /bin/sh \
    registry:2 bin/registry garbage-collect --delete-untagged /etc/docker/registry/config.yml
```

Make sure to test `--delete-untagged` before using it in any production environment. Last time I looked at the code, I think it was to aggressive with multi-platform images. At some point I'd like to rewrite it to be safe on running servers, and maybe just run periodically in the background instead of being a separate job.